# Version of thunderbird that doesn't require installation?

Tags: thunderbird, portable

Is there a binary version of Thunderbird, which I can just unzip and run, without having to install it?

I have done quite a bit of Googling and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/) has [one](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable).

Comment: I was confused by the download file having an .exe extension, and thought it would work only on a USB drive with the portable apps suite. Thanks.